# How to fetch column values from a php array?

Tags: php, arrays

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [filename] => Volume Selection
        [column_arr] => Array
            (
                [seq_num] => Array
                    (
                        [data_type] => N
                    )
                [user_code] => Array
                    (
                        [data_type] => C
                        [min_char] => 15
                    )
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [filename] => Job File
        [column_arr] => Array
            (
                [prop_seq_num] => Array
                    (
                        [data_type] => N
                    )
                [prop_user_code] => Array
                    (
                        [data_type] => C
                        [min_char] => 15
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

I want to fetch the *column_arr* subarray from each entry in it's entirety?
How would I get only those values out of this array

I tried this

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value1)
```

But here I just get the all values from the subarray

Comment: What have you tried so far? PHP offers a handy function via [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) for iterating arrays

Comment: you want get all values for "filename" field from only first depth level or any level?

Comment: `Array[0].filename` would give you the fist file name similarly the file name at second index can be retrieved.

Comment: and what is wrong with all the answers? could you explain that? because you are answering everyone to read question, and most of answers do what you are asking for. oh ok, I see you totally changed question... sorry `-1` for that.

Comment: @FlashThunder :I edited the question thats y I wrote that

Comment: @user3675101 ok, but editing question that it asks for totally different thing is making a mess... if you want to ask another thing, just make another qestion... those answers were valid for original question.

Comment: @FlashThunder :-1 ..:(

Answer (score 3):

Use the function [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/array_column).

for example:

```
$filenames = array_column(myArray, "filename");
foreach ( $filenames as $filename )
    echo $filename;
```

**edit** You have edited your question. Now this would be your solution:

```
$column_arrs = array_column(myArray, "column_arr");
foreach ( $column_arrs as $key => $column_arr )
    echo $key;
```

Comment: @trizz in stead of copying my answer and appending a link to a polyfill in case PHP < 5.5 , you could have just commented this one. OP did not state he is using an old(er) php version

Comment: If your answer was on my screen when I wrote my answer, I would have added the comment. But it wasn't, so I've added my own answer. But I will delete it if it is such a problem to you :)

Comment: @trizz Too late. I have already assigned this case to my lawyers ;)

Comment: As I have deleted my answer en thus the mentioned link: if you don't use PHP 5.5, you can use [this library](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column) as an alternative for the same function. @nl-x nice :D Always wanted to meet other SO users IRL ;)

Comment: I tried this and getting Call to undefined function array_column()  Fatal error

Comment: @user3675101 Please see the comment of trizz for an alternative to `array_column()`. (The library link)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer that, because noone probably will. Again will get accused for answering only to get more points, but I don't care. Everyone was new in progamming some day.

```
$array = <your array>;    
$filenames = array();
foreach($array as $elem){
   if($elem['filename'])
       $filenames[] = $elem['filename'];
}
print_r($filenames);
```

Comment: well this wont work bro, since OP mentioned that its array inside an array

Comment: where? can't see that.

Comment: if you check the Question  above posted with sample array structure, you will understand

Comment: it's array of arrays of records... everything seems to be fine. `foreach` iterates through top level array and displays `filename` fields from arrays inside...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
foreach($arr as $value) {
    echo $value['filename'] . '<br/>';
}
```

This will print all of the required values.

Comment: well this wont work, since OP mentioned that its array inside an array

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$arr = array( array ( 'filename' => 'Volume Selection',
                      'column_arr' => array( 'seq_num' => array( 'data_type' => 'N' ) ),
                      'user_code' => array( 'data_type' => 'C', 'min_char' => '15' )
                    ),
              array ( 'filename' => 'Job File',
                      'column_arr' => array( 'seq_num' => array( 'data_type' => 'N' ) ),
                      'user_code' => array( 'data_type' => 'C', 'min_char' => '15' )
                    )
            );

foreach( $arr as $subarr )
{
    if ( $subarr['filename'] == 'Job File' )
    {
        print_r( $subarr ) ;
    }
}
```